# mysql return record in where clause

Tags: mysql

I am struck to get all products where are exists in category_id 6,3
for this i am using.

`select c.product_id from product_to_category c where c.category_id = 6 and c.category_id = 3`

for this its return 0 record

if i use `OR` instead of `AND`,

`select c.product_id from product_to_category c where c.category_id = 6 or c.category_id = 3`

then, it return all specific products related to 6 or 3 `category_id`

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want all record of category 6 & 3? if yes then using `OR` should do it. whats the problem in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use IN

```
select c.product_id from product_to_category c where c.category_id IN (6,3)
```

When you are using AND then it is checking the value c.category_id as 6 and 3 which looks like is not possible in your case. When you are using OR then it like you are checking if c.category_id to be 3 or 6 ie, either of it.

Comment: yes it return many records,like some products exists in category 6 some are in 3 and some are in both (6,3), but i need just those records whose exists in (6,3)

Comment: @HassanFarooq:- You can use Gordon's query in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregation:

```
select c.product_id
from product_to_category c
where c.category_id in (3, 6)
group by c.product_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query -- you are looking for products who have a particular set of product ids.  I like to approach this using `group by` and `having`, because this very flexibly handles many different conditions.

If you can have duplicates, the `having` clause should be:

```
having count(distinct c.category_id) = 2
```